# Error al acceder a ficheros en el mismo directorio

Tags: python

Estoy intentando acceder a un archivo de lectura en el mismo directorio que el programa, pero al iniciarlo me da el siguiente error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'texto.txt'
```

El código:

```
from io import open 
f = open("texto.txt", 'r')
```

Comment: Ejecuta un `print(os.getcwd())` antes de abrir y fijate en que directorio estas parado.

Comment: Probablemente estás lanzando tu programa desde algún IDE. Algunos ejecutan el programa desde una carpeta diferente de la que ocupa el script .py y por ahí puede venir el problema. Por otro lado, `open()` es una función _builtin_. No necesitas importarla de `io` (`io.open()` es un alias para `open()`)